# React MUI Autocomplete with Formik and custom render options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, formik

I am trying to implement React Material UI `Autocomplete` component by using `Formik` (setFormValue) and custom `renderOption` property, so I don't use **TextField** component, but custom **input** field.

Filtering options works as expected, so when I enter some value in custom input, the results are displayed depending on what I typed in, but I have an issue with selecting an option. When I click when I click one of the offered ones, nothing happens.

I created `FilterDropdown` component so it can be reusable. Please see my code and tell me where I wrong.

I did debugging through Google chrome breakpoints, and when I click on any available dropdown option, nothing happens.

**filter-dropdown/index.tsx**

```
import { createElement } from 'react'
import { Divider } from '@eframe-ui/react'
import { FilterDropdownProps, DropdownOptionProps } from './types'
import { Translate } from '../translate'
import { Autocomplete } from '@mui/material'
import { FilterDropdownInput } from './Input'

export const FilterDropdown = ({
  data,
  dropdownDataLayout,
  selectFieldLabel,
  fieldValue,
  errors,
  setFieldValue,
}: FilterDropdownProps) => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      className="gap-y-1 flex flex-col"
      options={data}
      getOptionLabel={(option: string | DropdownOptionProps) =>
        (option as { value: string }).value
      } // filter value
      onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue(fieldValue, value)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <FilterDropdownInput
          error={errors}
          params={params}
          label={selectFieldLabel}
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(props, option: DropdownOptionProps) => {
        const { label, mixin } = option

        return dropdownDataLayout
          ? createElement(dropdownDataLayout, mixin as Record<string, string>)
          : label && (
              <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                <Translate label={label} />
                <Divider className="!my-2" />
              </div>
            )
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

**Input.tsx**

```
import { TextField } from '@/../ui'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { AutocompleteRenderInputParams } from '@mui/material'

interface FilterDropdownProps {
  params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams
  label: string
  error: string | JSX.Element | undefined
}

export const FilterDropdownInput = ({
  params,
  label,
  error,
}: FilterDropdownProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  return (
    <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
      <TextField
        {...params.inputProps}
        label={t(label)}
        placeholder={t('common:Field.Search', 'Enter search term')}
        error={!!error}
        helperText={error}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**transfer-assets.tsx**

```
  const TransferAssetsLayout = (option: Record<string, string>) => (
    <div
      className="funds flex flex-col w-full cursor-pointer"
      onClick={() => setFieldValue('pension_fund_name', option.name)}
    >
      <p className="text-text-primary typo-regular-300 px-2">{option.name}</p>
      {option.recipient && (
        <p
          className={clsx(
            classes.italic,
            'text-text-secondary typo-regular-200 px-2 pb-1',
          )}
        >
          {option.recipient}
        </p>
      )}
      <p
        className={clsx(
          classes.italic,
          'text-text-secondary typo-regular-200 px-2 pb-1',
        )}
      >
        {`${option.address}, ${option.zip_code} ${option.location}`}
      </p>
      <Divider className="!m-0" />
    </div>
  )

    <FilterDropdown
      data={pensionFundsData}
      dropdownDataLayout={TransferAssetsLayout}
      selectFieldLabel="USM-PortfolioEdit:TransferAssets.InstitutionName"
      fieldValue={'pension_fund_name'}
      buttonLabel={pension_fund_name}
      setFieldValue={() => setFieldValue}
      errors={errors.pension_fund_name}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue , this is my solution

```
import { createElement, HTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { Divider } from '@eframe-ui/react'
import { FilterDropdownProps, DropdownOptionProps } from './types'
import { Translate } from '../translate'
import { Autocomplete, Paper } from '@mui/material'
import { FilterDropdownInput } from './Input'

export const FilterDropdown = ({
  data,
  dropdownDataLayout,
  selectFieldLabel,
  fieldValue,
  errors,
  setFieldValue,
}: FilterDropdownProps) => {
  /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
  const CustomPaper = (props: any) => (
    <Paper {...props} sx={{ background: '#f4f7fa', marginTop: '4px' }} />
  )

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      className="gap-y-1 flex flex-col"
      options={data}
      getOptionLabel={(option: string | DropdownOptionProps) =>
        (option as { value: string }).value
      } // filter value
      onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue(fieldValue, value)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <FilterDropdownInput
          {...params}
          error={errors}
          params={params}
          label={selectFieldLabel}
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(
        props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>,
        option: DropdownOptionProps,
      ) => {
        const { label, mixin } = option

        return (
          <>
            <li {...props} className="w-full cursor-pointer">
              {dropdownDataLayout
                ? createElement(
                    dropdownDataLayout,
                    mixin as Record<string, string>,
                  )
                : label && (
                    <>
                      <Translate label={label} />
                      <Divider className="!my-2" />
                    </>
                  )}
            </li>
          </>
        )
      }}
      PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the MUI input props or `Autocomplete` loses track of your custom input.

Instead of this:

```
renderInput={(params) => (
  <FilterDropdownInput
    error={errors}
    params={params}
    label={selectFieldLabel}
  />
)}
```

Use this:

```
renderInput={(params) => (
  <FilterDropdownInput
    {...params}
    error={errors}
    params={params}
    label={selectFieldLabel}
  />
)}
```

Example [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-autocomplete-textfield-c837m1) of MUI Autocomplete passing props down to through `renderInput`. You must use `{...params}` exactly as can be verified.

```
<Autocomplete
  options={someData.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  disabled={(someData || []).length >= 5}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      size="small"
      label="Type some stuff"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Still nothing.  {...params} didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Seems you're using `{...params.inputProps}` instead of `{...params}`

Comment: I found what's the issue in my case, the problem is because of dynamic layout and createElement. Is there any way to provide dynamic layout as component in renderOption, because this works but without desired layout - return <div {...props}>{option.value}</div>